# Splitting the elements of a pipe separated column from a tab separated command output

Tags: awk

I am parsing a text file with irregular format into a text file with 10 columns using the following command.

```
bcftools query -Hf 'CHC2432T\t%TYPE\t%CHROM\t%POS\t%REF\t%ALT\t%ANN[\t%DP\t%AD\t%GT]\n' test.vcf > ttest.txt
```

the results is a `tab-separated` text file with 10 column BUT the 7th column (which `ANN` in the command) contains several elements which is | separated like this example:

```
G|intron_variant|MODIFIER|C1orf222|ENSG00000142609|transcript|ENST00000493316|protein_coding
```

I would like to get the 4th element of this `|` separated column instead of the above row (the whole row).
I am trying to do that in AWK using the following command (added to the above command):

```
bcftools query -Hf 'CHC2432T\t%TYPE\t%CHROM\t%POS\t%REF\t%ALT\t%ANN[\t%DP\t%AD\t%GT]\n' test.vcf | awk '{printf }' | awk -F "|" '{print $1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5\t$6\t$7\t$8\t$9\t$10}' > results.txt
```

but it does not return what I want to get. do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pipe the output of your `bcftools` to a single `awk` command that does this

```
bcftools query -Hf 'CHC2432T\t%TYPE\t%CHROM\t%POS\t%REF\t%ALT\t%ANN[\t%DP\t%AD\t%GT]\n' test.vcf |
    awk -v FS="\t" '{ split($7, arr, "|"); $7 = arr[4] }1'
```

You could further improve your `awk` command to introduce a sanity check to ensure you are *not* accessing an out of bound array member